# AngularJS - Apply required attribute conditionally based on radio button value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have the following in my form in-order to validate, what should happen is when user clicks citizen radio buttons 'sno' is displayed/hidden according to yes/no. But I need to remove the 'required' attribute of 'sno' when user clicks "No" simultanouely, in-order to prevent validating 'sno'.

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="citizen" value="Yes" citizen-check>Yes
<input type="radio" ng-model="citizen" value="No">No

<div ng-show='enableNo()'>
    <div id="view">
        <input type="text" id="sno" name="sno" required>
    </div>
</div>
<div ng-hide='enableNo()'>
    <div id="view">
        <input type="text" id="pno" name="pno" required>
    </div>
</div>
```

Inside controller I have the following for show/hide feature,

```
$scope.enableNo= function()
    {
        $log.log('enableNo called');
        if($scope.citizen == 'Yes')
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }   
    }
```

How do I write a directive to remove 'required' attribute of 'sno'?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use `ngRequired`.

`ngRequired` adds `required` attribute and `required` validation constraint to the element when the ngRequired expression evaluates to true.

```
<!-- adds 'required' attribute when ngRequired expression evaluates to true -->
<input type="text" id="sno" name="sno" ng-required="citizen == 'Yes'">
```

Comment: I want my validations for 'sno' not to fire when user clicks "No". it doesnt happen when using your way

Comment: given the condition it works. Thx for the explanation.

Comment: @CodeHater, have a look into same type of problem with buttons http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42997379/conditional-required-validation-with-buttons-in-angularjs

Comment: Good answer. I was conditionally adding the required attribute like so: `ng-attr-required="ifCondition || undefined"` but it didn't work. This works well.