# Conditional Required Validation with buttons in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I having two buttons as Save and Submit and some of the drop-downs and text-boxes. There is need to validate some of the fields on click of Submit, not on click of Save. Please find the code in below.

```
<button class="btn btn-default custom_edit" 
                            data-ng-click="orderForm.$valid && saveOrder('save')" 
                            data-ng-if="!order.IsSubmitted"
                            data-ng-model="status"
                            value="save">Save</button>
<button class="btn btn-success" 
                            data-ng-click="orderForm.$valid && saveOrder('submit')" 
                            data-ng-if="!order.IsSubmitted"
                            data-ng-model="status"
                            value="submit">Submit</button>

 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="_requisition" placeholder="Requisition"
                                        data-ng-model="order.Requisition"
                                        data-ng-trim="true"
                                        data-ng-required="status=='save'"/>
```

I have tried by using value & model with buttons and applied it with ng-required , however it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using input type as 'submit', validation can be maintained as well as other function can be also called as form is valid.

```
<input type="submit" value="Save"
                            data-ng-click="isSave = true; orderForm.$valid && saveOrder('save')" 
                            data-ng-model="isSave" 
                            data-ng-show="!order.IsSubmitted"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"
                            data-ng-click="isSave = false; orderForm.$valid && saveOrder('submit')" 
                            data-ng-model="isSave"  
                            data-ng-show="!order.IsSubmitted"/>

<input type="text" class="form-control" name="_requisition" placeholder="Requisition"
                            data-ng-model="order.Requisition"
                            data-ng-trim="true"
                            maxlength="100"
                            data-ng-required="isSave"/>
```

So by this way, we can easily set model value on button click at run time as well as can validate form.